# WebRTC browser-to-app, only browser gets the stream

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc

I have created a react-native test app for testing WebRTC using Firebase real-time database for signaling.  It works between two Android phones.  I tried to test browser-to-phone streaming by creating a browser version with Javascript.  When the stream is established, only the browser receives the remote stream from the phone, while the phone does not receive the stream from the browser.

I look at the offer and candidates generated by the browser and they look valid to me.  But here's something odd I found on the browser version.  After offer is created, then I setLocalDescription, and then write the offer object to the database:

```
var offer = await localPC.createOffer({offerToReceiveVideo: true, offerToReceiveAudio: true});
await localPC.setLocalDescription(offer);
var offerDesc = localPC.localDescription;
dbReference.set({
    name: 'Test',
    desc: offerDesc,
    type: 'offer',
  });
```

The above codes work without a problem in the react-native version.  The offerDesc is an object with "type" and "sdp" keys.  In the browser version, the offerDesc is also an object with "type" and "sdp" keys.  But when writing to the database it got ignored.  On the browser version, in order to write it to the database, I have to write it as a string instead of an object using JSON.stringify().  That is very odd.  I wonder if they offer generated from the browser version has a problem, but it looks valid.  Here's an example of the offer generated by the browser version:

```
{"sdp": "v=0
o=- 3945637527721089108 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0 1
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:VvkQ
a=ice-pwd:3pJ4EgST4YPmjN4+6Qk0HYMU
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 88:E0:6F:18:BF:62:D0:F7:9B:6E:41:55:15:C3:7C:C7:7A:6F:00:CF:83:76:BF:37:4C:4C:D4:E9:0A:9D:B0:41
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 122 102 121 127 120 125 107 108 109 124 119 123 118 114 115 116
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:VvkQ
a=ice-pwd:3pJ4EgST4YPmjN4+6Qk0HYMU
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 88:E0:6F:18:BF:62:D0:F7:9B:6E:41:55:15:C3:7C:C7:7A:6F:00:CF:83:76:BF:37:4C:4C:D4:E9:0A:9D:B0:41
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:1
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:12 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:11 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 profile-id=2
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:122 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:122 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:122 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:122 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:122 nack
a=rtcp-fb:122 nack pli
a=fmtp:122 profile-id=1
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:102 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:102 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=102
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli
a=fmtp:123 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001f
a=rtpmap:118 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:118 apt=123
a=rtpmap:114 red/90000
a=rtpmap:115 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:115 apt=114
a=rtpmap:116 ulpfec/90000
", "type": "offer"}
```

What could be the problem??

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem by comparing my steps to the example at [CodeLabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web#0).  I missed the line of codes that add the local stream to my local peer connection after I started the local stream and the created the local peer connection:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
  .then(function(stream) {
    localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    ......
    localPC = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
    ......
    localPC.addStream(stream); //this is the line I missed
  })
```

When missing this line, there is no local stream to be sent to the remote peer.  It has nothing to do with the offer or candidates.